# codeigniter session is not working at godaddy hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have created two codeignter controllers at godaddy hosting with following code
Mysession.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mysession extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->helper('url');
}

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('fullname', 'David Beckham');  
        echo "<a href='".base_url()."index.php/mysession2'>Click here </a>";    


    }

}
```

And next controller is 
Mysession2.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mysession2 extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->helper('url');

}

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        echo $this->session->userdata('fullname');  
    }

}
```

What my suppose with these file is http://goldmarktravel.com.au/index.php/mysession may set the session name fullname with value "david beckham" and when i try to access http://goldmarktravel.com.au/index.php/mysession2 it may display the value . But its not showing any data. Its working finely on other server except godaddy hosting.

Comment: You need to check config carefully ! Local and server environment is different

Comment: Show your session and cookie configs. Your problem is almost certainly related to the setup. Also, have you set `$config['base_url']` appropriately?

Comment: Have you set your session save path in the config.php please edit your question with your session and cookie config.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'     = Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
| 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
|
| Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
|       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.yourdoamin.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

And rather loading the library on each controller you can auto load it on config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Comment: I did same but not working, is there any issue regarding godaddy hosting so that we should consider something for session on codeigniter????

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH. 'cache/sessions/';
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code. Code only answers are not good.